# WebView: prevent content from being half on/off the screen?

Tags: java, javascript, android, web

I have a mostly full screen WebView, and often a line of text or a image will be half on screen and half off due to the current scroll position. Is there any way to snap lines & images to the screen? I feel that the solution may be to use JS and parse the document and insert wrapper divs around each screenful and to hide/show these wrapper divs one at a time.

So my question is that if this sounds like the best plan, how do I detect if a paragraph of text is wrapped to x number of lines, and where the wrapping took place? While I could more easily just detect if whole paragraphs would be clipped and show that paragraph on the next page that could cause problems if a paragraph won't fit on 1 screen.

Here is a image showing the issue. See the image in the top is only partially shown, and the bottom line of text is also partially shown.

![image]

Answer (score 0):

Very hacky and completely untested, but might be helpful

```
var baseOfScreenPosition = $.scrollTop() + $(window).height();

$(".book_paragraph).each( function(i) { 
var topOfParagraph = $(this).offset().height;
    var bottomOfParagraph = topOfParagraph + $(this).height();

    if( baseOfScreenPosition > topOfParaGraph && baseOfScreenPosition < bottomOfParagraph)
    {
    // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I have the viewport setup identical to this, this prevents clipping on the sides, but not top/bottom. See picture I added.

Comment: Ok I understand now. You could try to calculate how far the user has gone down the page. If $.scrollTop() is between the top and bottom of the paragraph you could try to hide it. (or move it to the next page)